# Amazon Alexa account linking using Keycloak is not working

Tags: keycloak, alexa-account-linking

I'm working on a custom skill which should allow account linking with a platform using Keycloak. Implicit Grant flow works fine, when switching to Authorization Code flow, it's not. From Alexa docs (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/configure-authorization-code-grant.html#tokens), I understand that on access-token request Alexa does not send the redirect_uri, which is mandatory (according to RFC 6749, the standard that Amazon claims it follows) and also Keycloak enforces to use it (request fails without it). Did anyone else had this issue? Is there any workaround in Keycloak to overcome this constraint?